# Automatic disabling the menu items

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a menu bar in my home page, when i click on the menu item it will display the list in that menu. until i press some where else in the home page the menu list will be remains same.
when i press some position in the page then only the drop down menu list going away.

i want to make the list disappear as soon as i press on list of menu item. how can i do that.
i really appreciate your time.
thanks in advance.

i tried this:

```
     <li class="menu">Initialization
            <ul class="links">
                                <%--<li><a href="refresh.jsp" target="first">Refresh</a></li>--%>
                                    <li><a href="programme_mang.jsp" target="first"> Programme Management</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="subject_database.jsp" target="first">Subject Database</a></li>
                <li><a href="faculty_database.jsp" target="first">Faculty Database</a></li>
                                    <%--<li><a href="cFile.jsp" target="first">Load Curriculum</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="addSubject.jsp" target="first">Add Subject</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="addFaculty.jsp" target="first">Add Faculty</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="deleteSubject.jsp" target="first">Delete Subject</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="deleteFaculty.jsp" target="first">Delete Faculty</a></li>--%>
                                    <li><a href="phd_electives.jsp" target="first">Ph.D electives</a></li>
                                    <li><a href="astaff5.jsp" target="first">Grade Formula</a></li>

            </ul>
        </li>
```

Edited :

JS:

```
        window.addEvent('domready', function(){
    $('drop_down_menu').getElements('li.menu').each( function( elem ){
        var list = elem.getElement('ul.links'); 
        var myFx = new Fx.Slide(list).hide();           
        elem.addEvents({
            'mouseenter' : function(){                  
                myFx.cancel();
                myFx.slideIn();                 
            },
            'mouseleave' : function(){ 
                myFx.cancel();
                myFx.slideOut();                    
            }
        }); 
    })
});
```

Comment: ...and any JS/Jquery?

Comment: make a fiddle for this

Comment: Give me some example @REX

Comment: example?? http://jsfiddle.net/ copy paste your code and save then share link

Comment: here i did post in $http://jsfiddle.net/SLxr3/